# I am not able to change voices using pyttsx3 module! Any indexing returns me DAVID only

Tags: python, python-3.x, voice-recognition, pyttsx

I am trying to build a virtual assistant. I need a voice called PaulM which is present in my regedit. But any index returns me only DAVID voice, not even ZIRA or any other.

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices', voices[2].id)
i=0
while i<5:
    print(voices[i].id)
    i += 1
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)

volume = engine.getProperty('volume')
engine.setProperty('volume',0.5 )

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak('Good morning')
    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Hi there, Good Afternoon")
    else:
        speak("Hi there, Good Evening")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wishMe()
    speak("Good morning and thank you for one more day of knowing me to the core but still not leaving me. You’re a good friend indeed!")
```

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN-US_DAVID_11.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN-GB_HAZEL_11.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\MSTTS_V110_frFR_PaulM
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_FR-FR_HORTENSE_11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't depend on pyttsx3 . The voices come from 'sapi5' .So make sure to download the latest version of sapi5 from - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10121      If your computer has pre-installed sapi5 then you need to check how old your computer is as the voices have now been changed to 2 but it wasn't always the same . Before there was only David . HTH

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code, the same problem was with me. And I solved it, let me tell you. This is your code:

```
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voices', voices[2].id)
```

and correct it by replacing your code with:

```
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[2].id)
```

Just remove "s" from "voices", IDK this is a bug. But somehow the error is not displayed.

Hope this helps!